.Net blazor with FluentUI library - How to make FluentStack take all free space in the page
Just want to know if I can say to a FluentStack, in a .Net blazor server app, that it should grow and take all the free space there is in the page.
I'm using this FluentStack and it just takes what it needs, the length of its content, but not the remaining free space:
<FluentStack Style="border: 1px solid lightgray; width: 100%; ">
  ---content--- 
</FluentStack> 

Notice I'm using a border to see the space it takes.
Even if I add a Style with with: 100%, it does not grow to take all the remaining free space.
Somebody know how to make the FluentStack grow horizontally and take all free space that remains in the page???
Many thanks for your help and bye ...

The FLuentUi templates use the css classes .body-content and .content. The first is 100 width and height, the later is only width. These classes are used in MainLayout.razor they are defined in wwwroot\css\app.css.

Hi Brian Parker. Could you give a hint on how to use those classes to make a FluentStack grow 100% of the page space? I mean, horizontally ...

Well, it seems you have to add an style="width: 100%; " to the div just above @Body. Like this (MainLayout.razor):
<FluentStack Class="main" Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal">
    <NavMenu />
    <FluentBodyContent Class="body-content">
        <div class="content" style="width: 100%; ">
            @Body
        </div>
    </FluentBodyContent>
</FluentStack>

Then whatever is inside that @body can grow horizontally to the end of the page.
It seems the css classes: body-content and content don't restrict stuff growing horizontally. I have very limited css skills though, so I found this solution just by trying adjustments here and there.
Thanks and bye ...
